# How to check if element is present in array and if present then update this

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having an array of Hashmap and I want to check if Hashmap is present in an array and if the Hashmap persists, then update that particular Hashmap otherwise just create a new Hashmap in an array.
the criterion of checking would be playerId only.

Given below is the 2 HashMap in an array that would make you clear what I wanted.

```
[
{ 
playerID: 1037510,
buntingForAHit: 0,
 pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0,
 usingClosers: 0
},

{
playerID: 1075714,
 buntingForAHit: 0, 
pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0, 
usingClosers: 0
}

]
```

In the above code I want to check if player id is already present.
if present then just update it or overwrite it.Otherwise,if not present just create a new copy of it and add new Hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = list[0];
if (map.contains("playerId")) // id is present 
  map["playerId"] = update_id; // update it
else 
  map["playerId"] = new_id; // else add something new to it
```

Comment: I am adding Hashmap to list but unable to do so.      list.add(map); error:The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(_LinkedHashMap len:19)

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Don't try to call `add()` on `null`.  Ensure that `list` is initialized to an actual `List` instance first.